# PHP OpenCloud\Rackspace Problems

Tags: php, openstack, rackspace, php-opencloud

I am having problems trying to get the Rackspace Opencloud API to work as expected (particularly the cloud files).

I have been following these guides:

https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/docs/userguide/ObjectStore/Access.md
http://docs.rackspace.com/sdks/api/php/namespace-OpenCloud.ObjectStore.html

The Authentication seems to work fine because a token and the service catalog is returned.

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
require '/vendor/autoload.php';

use OpenCloud\Rackspace;

$client = new Rackspace('https://lon.identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/', array(
    'username' => 'MY_USERNAME',
    'apiKey'   => 'MY_APIKEY'
));

$client->authenticate();

echo 'Authenticated with token: '.$client->getToken()."\n\n";

print_r($client->getCatalog());
```

My problems start when i try to use a service from the API:

```
$service = $client->objectStoreService('cloudFiles');
```

This line kills the code. I have copied the Rackspace documentation line for line but still no luck, I am unable to get any of the services to work.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong or provide any tips for the best way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Hi Warren, would you mind posting a pastebin of the output of the catalog? Make sure to remove IDs and Tokens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Specify the region explicitly

You need to explicitly choose the region you want to use. From your identity line, it looks like you'll need to set it to LON.

```
$service = $client->objectStoreService('cloudFiles', 'LON'); # Or IAD, HKG, SYD, etc.
```

Side note: I just submitted a [pull request on php-opencloud](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/pull/259) to make this more clear in the documentation.

Comment: The answer is always simple! Thank you!